# VBA code for Ms Access distance between two Zip Codes or Address

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have been trying to calculate the distance between two zip codes using MS Access and I have written the following code:

```vb
Public Function GetDuration(start As String, dest As String)
    Dim firstVal As String, secondVal As String, lastVal As String
    firstVal = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins="
    secondVal = "&destinations="
    lastVal = "&mode=car&language=en&sensor=false"
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = firstVal & Replace(start, " ", "+") & secondVal & Replace(dest, " ", "+") & lastVal
    objHTTP.Open "GET", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
    If InStr(objHTTP.responseText, """duration"" : {") = 0 Then GoTo ErrorHandl
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp"): regex.Pattern = "duration(?:.|\n)*?""value"".*?([0-9]+)": regex.Global = False
    Set matches = regex.Execute(objHTTP.responseText)
    Exit Function
ErrorHandl:
    GetDuration = -1
End Function
```

But it does not work properly. Can someone help me fix this code?

Answer (score 0):

Your regex is not matching only the numbers you want - http://regexr.com/3dfa8

Notice I took the JSON reply of the google maps API and applied your regex to it - it matches more than just the numbers you want.

I am not a master of regex myself so I would simply perform a substring ("mid" in Access) on your resulting regex match variable. In addition, you are not returning anything (you did not set GetDuration to anything before the end of your code, unless it executes the code after ErrorHandl tag). I'd try something like this:

```
Set match = matches(0)
Set value_pattern = """value"" : "
GetDuration = Mid(matches, InStr(matches, value_pattern)+Len(value_pattern), Len(matches))
```

I haven't tested but I think you will be able to fix your code with this.

Answer (score 0):

Can you setup a Form to look like this . . .

[image]

Then, add this script.

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Command0_Click()


Dim sXMLURL As String
Me.Text1.SetFocus
sXMLURL = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml?origins=" & Me.Text1.Text & "&destinations="
Me.Text2.SetFocus
sXMLURL = sXMLURL & Me.Text2.Text & "&mode=driving&language=en-US&units=imperial&sensor=false"

Dim objXMLHTTP As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Set objXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

With objXMLHTTP
    .Open "GET", sXMLURL, False
    .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
    .send
End With

'Debug.Print objXMLHTTP.responseText

Dim domResponse As DOMDocument60
Set domResponse = New DOMDocument60
domResponse.loadXML objXMLHTTP.responseText
Dim ixnStatus
Set ixnStatus = domResponse.selectSingleNode("//status")

'Debug.Print ixnStatus.Text

If ixnStatus.Text = "OK" Then
    Dim ixnDistance, ixnDuration
    Set ixnDistance = domResponse.selectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/text")
    Set ixnDuration = domResponse.selectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/duration/text")
    'Debug.Print "Distance: " & ixnDistance.Text
    'Debug.Print "Duration: " & ixnDuration.Text
    Me.Text3 = ixnDistance.Text
    Me.Text4 = ixnDuration.Text
End If

Me.Command0.SetFocus

Set domResponse = Nothing
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

End Sub
```

That should do it.

Comment: Please explain your approach for OP and future readers, namely that you are parsing the XML response rather than using regex on JSON response.

Answer (score 0):

See this forum for discussion on Google business model changes starting July 2018. The above code will not work without creating an account with Google and creating an API key. Also, note that the url link for google distance matrix starts with https rather than http.

https://www.access-programmers.co.uk/forums/showthread.php?t=225339&page=6

```
Private Sub cmdCalculate_Click()
    Dim strKey As String
    strKey = "AIzaSyAWSlNzPXIhnVwuGR6w9VigQJaSeXdplH4"

Dim sXMLURL As String
    Me.txtOrigin.SetFocus
    sXMLURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/xml? 
    origins=" & Me.txtOrigin.Text & "&destinations="
    Me.txtDest.SetFocus
    sXMLURL = sXMLURL & Me.txtDest.Text & "&mode=driving&language=en- 
    US&units=imperial&sensor=false"
    sXMLURL = sXMLURL & "&key=" & strKey

Dim objXMLHTTP As MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60
Set objXMLHTTP = New MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP60

With objXMLHTTP
.Open "GET", sXMLURL, False
.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-URLEncoded"
.send
End With

'Debug.Print objXMLHTTP.responseText

Dim domResponse As DOMDocument60
Set domResponse = New DOMDocument60
domResponse.loadXML objXMLHTTP.responseText
Dim ixnStatus
Set ixnStatus = domResponse.selectSingleNode("//status")

'Debug.Print ixnStatus.Text

If ixnStatus.Text = "OK" Then
Dim ixnDistance, ixnDuration
Set ixnDistance =domResponse.selectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/distance/text")
    Set ixnDuration = domResponse.selectSingleNode("/DistanceMatrixResponse/row/element/duration/text")
'Debug.Print "Distance: " & ixnDistance.Text
'Debug.Print "Duration: " & ixnDuration.Text
Me.txtDistance = ixnDistance.Text
Me.txtDuration = ixnDuration.Text
End If

Me.cmdCalculate.SetFocus

Set domResponse = Nothing
Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing

End Sub
```